# Python Date mid-way between two dates

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
raw_data = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'SeriesDate':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15']}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['Series_Date','SeriesDate'])
print df
```

To this DF, I would like to append four columns at the end:

1) Start_Date = SeriesDate - 10 Business Days

2) End_Date = SeriesDate - 3 Business Days

3) Date_Difference = (End_Date - Start_Date)/2. However, if the date difference is 4.5 days the value should be 5 and not 4 i.e. it should round up.

4) Roll_Date = End_Date - 'Date_Difference' Business Days. i.e. if Date_Difference is 5 then the Roll_Date = End_Date - 5 Business Days

I am able to append the first two columns as follows:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
df['Start_Date'] = df['SeriesDate'] - BDay(10)
df['End_Date'] = df['SeriesDate'] - BDay(3)
```

However, I am struggling with the last 2 columns. Could anyone provide some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have this `df`:

```
  Series_Date Start_Date   End_Date
0  2017-03-10 2017-02-24 2017-03-07
1  2017-03-13 2017-02-27 2017-03-08
2  2017-03-14 2017-02-28 2017-03-09
3  2017-03-15 2017-03-01 2017-03-10
```

You can complete the 2 columns:

```
df['Date_Difference'] = ((df.End_Date - df.Start_Date) / 2).dt.ceil('D')
df['Roll_Date'] = df.End_Date - pd.Series(BDay(dd.days) for dd in df.Date_Difference)
```

Explanation:

`(df.End_Date - df.Start_Date) / 2)` gives a Series of timedeltas. `.dt.ceil('D')` rounds this Series up to the day.

`pd.Series(BDay(dd.days) for dd in df.Date_Difference)` creates a Series of BusinessDays based on the number of days in `Date_Difference`. (There is very likely a better way to do it, but I'm a newbie with pandas).

Side question: why do you have 2 columns `Series_Date` and `SeriesDate` with the same content ?

Comment: Thanks whats dt though? Is it an external library that I need to import.

Comment: .dt is an attribute available in any Series containing datetimes like objects, and which contains datetime related methods, such as `ceil()` in our case. See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties

Comment: Thanks, when trying to subtract using BDay i.e. 
    df['Start_Date'] = df['SeriesDate'] - BDay(10). I am getting a TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O') error. Any possible workaround?